# scedule post on facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to scedule a post on a facebook page :
https://graph.facebook.com/898816883506941/feed?message=test&published=false&scheduled_publish_time=475222121&access_token=

I got this error :
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"BD2bScn5NxI"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Page Token of the Page, with the `publish_pages` permission.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: extended page tokens are valid forever, i will add some links to my answer